# How to dynamically create objects from a file?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, dynamic

I'm reading in files such as this with multiple lines like this.

"title,name,something,something,something"

How would I dynamically create new objects with those variables

I am splitting it already -

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    lineFromFile = reader.ReadLine();

    split = lineFromFile.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

}
```

My class is called Modules. Just don't know how to do it dynamically since I don't know how many modules will be in the file ETC.

Comment: Sounds like you need an array of your object and add new instances using the object initializer.

Comment: Are properties fixed in otherwords do you've only 5 properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `List<Module>` and add all items read from your file there:

```
List<Module> modules = new List<Module>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    lineFromFile = reader.ReadLine();

    split = lineFromFile.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var newModule = new Module();
    newModule.Property1 = split[0];
    newModule.Property2 = split[1];

    // (...) //

    modules.Add(newModule);

}
```

Or using LINQ:

```
var modules = (from line in File.ReadAllLines("fileName")
               let parts = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               select new Module() {
                   Property1 = parts[0],
                   Property2 = parts[1],
                   Property3 = parts[2],
               }).ToList();
```